# subdomain htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I have searched Google for this thing but nothing found
I would like to redirect any sub-domain to new page which is located in new directory

example:
if people write http://subdomain.example.com it will automatically redirect to http://subdomain.example.com/newdirectory/new-index.php

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do a url rewriting redirection

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule    ^(.*)$  / newdirectory/$1 [R]
```

In my example I presumed new-index.php is actually call index.php so that it is easier and makes more sense to me.

Have a look at:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html